# Selecting link inside href PHP

Tags: php, regex

How do I select `http://test.com/` out of this HTML: 
`<a target="_new" href="http://test.com/" title="test">$293.00</a>`

I realize I should use a DOM parser, however its for a few lines of code and I'd rather just use regex.

I've tried this with no success:

```
preg_match('/(http|https)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/', $html, $url);
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's why you should use a DOM parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with *lookarounds*:

```
if (preg_match('/(?<=href=").*?(?=")/', $html, $groups)) {
    $url = $groups[0];
} else {
    $url = "";
}
```

- `(?<=href=")` means: find a position immediately after `href="`
- Then match anything, but as little as possible with `.*?` -- this is saved in `groups[0]`
- Stop, when you found a position where the next character is `"`

Comment: @Dean: How do you mean? The HTML code should be in the $html variable.

Comment: that's correct. I've just noticed though I'm doing this: `strip_tags($html)` - which would cause this error. I'll see what I can do with it, because if I change this it will break a fair bit of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

When I don't use a DOM parser, it means that I am pretty sure about the contents, and end up with something REALLY simple... like this...

```
preg_match('/href="([^"]+)"/', $html, $regs);
```

url will be in $regs[1].

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the href, all you have to do is `preg_match('/href="([^"]*?)/', $html, $matches)` and then grab the content of `$matches[1]`.

Comment: Does not work, returns `array(0) { } ` with a `var_dump($url);` this also doesnt return anything: `echo $url[1];` using code: `preg_match('/href="([^"]+)"/', $html, $url);`

Comment: yeah, see above comments for why. I got it working now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, certainly your parser doesn't match tons of legal URLs.  More usefully, see http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Note more specifically, /\S* matches /" which is not what you want, presumably.